# Nested Each with Inner Value as key for Outer Object: Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am making a help to use for multi-col tables. In the helper you specify which object columns you want to display and with nested each loops it should all work. I have the values I need where I want them but I can't get handlebars to use the inner string value as a key for the outer value.

I have an almost working [PLNKR here with all the code in it.](https://plnkr.co/edit/clNLOA8CX72FgNrJeP4t?p=preview) which you can play around with.

It almost works..

The short part of the code where I'm having an issue is:

```
<table>
 {{#items}}
  <tr >
    {{#each ../colNames}}
      <td>{{../this}}.{{this}}</td>
    {{/each}}
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" 
        id="masterList{{@index}}"
        {{#if this.selected}}checked{{/if}}
        onchange="{{../checkAction}}({{@index}})"
      >
    </td>
  </tr>
 {{/items}}
</table>
```

Even more specifically:

```
<td>{{../this}}.{{this}}</td>
```

I have tried things like:

```
<td>{{../this}}.[{{this}}]</td>
<td>{{../this}}.[this]}}</td>
<td>{{../this.this}}</td>
<td>{{../this.(this)}}</td>
```

The closest I get returns like (with column names given to the helper "name" and "score"):

```
<td>[object Object].name</td>   
<td>[object Object].score</td>
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas to solve or work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!

```
{{lookup ../this this}}
```